# Need to know if a given date has expired or not

Tags: php, datetime

I need to know how can i get to know in php that whether a given date is expired or not? I need to show the status of the same in a package manager where I need to know whether the package is active or expired. I have 2 fields in mysql table called start_date and expiry_date.

I need to know how can I subtract the expiry_date from star_date and get the value and then check whether that expiry_date is expired or yet to expire.

Please help me.

Comment: [What you have tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: How does an expiry date expire? If you want to check if a date is in the past, convert it to a timestamp and check it against the current timestamp.

Comment: Here you can find all php Date/Time functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php

Comment: @asad, expiry_date here is a field in my table which holds the date when the package is going to expire. A future date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I'm going to make a few assumptions so that my answer can be more clear.

If your expiry_date is the date that the package expires, you can use php to check whether it is a date in the future or not like so.

```
$exp_date = strtotime($expiry_date);

if(time() > $exp_date) // your package has expired.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try DATEDIFF in MySQL

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(expiry_date,start_date) AS difference FROM packages...
```

Or in PHP you could iterate through the answers and select something like:

```
 $curr_date = date('Y-m-d'); // or your date format

// loop

if ($row['start_date'] <= $curr_date && $row['expiry_date'] > $curr_date){
  // post is active
}
elseif ($row['expiry_date'] > $curr_date)
{
   // post expired
}
```

Comment: thnks buddy for your help, it helped me to achieve what I was trying to achieve. Appreciated :)

Comment: @user1530513 Cool, great i helped. But the other answer is still your accepted answer? at least can you upvote this +1 ?